# Limit the number of pages displayed in spring

Tags: spring, pagination, sap-commerce-cloud

This is the code I use to create pagination page for data search.But I just noticed that I have too many records then it will have too many page numbers.I'm trying to limit the page number shown,and look for many examples ..it have many ways to do it but I still don't have idea how to limit it for my method?

```
<c:set var="current" value="${searchPageData.pagination.currentPage}"/>
        <c:set var="totalPageNumber" value="${searchPageData.pagination.numberOfPages -1}"/>
        <c:set var="limit" value="3"/>


        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${current != 0}">
                <a href="${baseURL}?page=${current -1}">&laquo;</a>
            </c:when>
        </c:choose>

        <c:forEach begin="0" end="${totalPageNumber}" varStatus="loop">
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${current == loop.index}">
                    <a href="${baseURL}?page=${loop.index}" class="active">${loop.index + 1}</a>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <a href="${baseURL}?page=${loop.index}">${loop.index + 1}</a>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        </c:forEach>

        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${current == totalPageNumber}"/>
            <c:otherwise>
                <a href="${baseURL}?page=${current +1}">&raquo;</a>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
```

this image show what ı did
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get what exactly you are searching for. Here are some reference from OOB hybris, you can use according to your implementation.

```
#Number of pagination results to display
pagination.number.results.count=5

#Number of pagination results for PickupInStore UI search
pointofservice.display.search.results.count=100
```

Configure this in your project.properties of your storefront!